# sms body not showing properly in android

Tags: android, html, css

I am on the way to developing my mobile app and i am using the following tag to send the msg to the users

```
<a href="sms://+3490322111?body=Interested%20in%20Product%20AA2">
More info for producto AA2</a>
```

I really works well. it goes to compose screen with the number correctly passing to the recipient section but the text is not passing, just want text also to passed and don't want to type anything while composing it.

kindly provide me a solution thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.

There is an [outstanding bug on android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12142) about body not being used even though it is part of the [Messaging API specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/messaging-api/#intro).

The same goes for iOS where [Safari's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html) mentions only phone and no body for SMS.

Comment: Ya really true. waiting for the bug to be fixed soon :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the message to be composed then.

I suggest you to send the sms explicitly via following method that uses SmsManager :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
   {
       SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
       sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
```

You also need to have permission to send sms in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your the time and help.. i use plain the html5 and css3 is there any way to achieve with these two ???